# Initializing a struct within a union within a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, unions

```
struct huffnode{
  int freq;
  union{
    struct children
    {
      struct huffnode * l;
      struct huffnode * r;
    }
    char c;
  }un;
};
```

I'm trying to create a program that implements a huffman tree but in order to do that I need to create nodes with a left and right node pointer in them. The problem is that I don't know how to initialize the struct children. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why you use union to store left and right child? In this way, you can only have one child at any time

Comment: @jujj No, if I initialise the struct I'll be able to have the 2 children inside it. So in essence I have either the struct children or the char c in the union.

Comment: @jujj Not true - look at it again.

Comment: Pls fix your indentantion, that's painful to read

Comment: The `struct children` is a syntax error, it should be `struct { struct huffnode *left, *right; } children;`, now it's anonymous which is going to be confusing.

Comment: @unwind Anonymous member structs are allowed since C11. There's a missing semicolon though.

Comment: Anyway, this code doesn't make any sense, particularly not "So in essence I have either the struct children or the char c in the union".

Comment: @Lundin I know, but it's still confusing, plus I wouldn't expect C11 compilers everywhere ... Perhaps I'm being overly catious.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  Yes, left and right child will both inside the union as i have test it. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think I have it now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: why Huffman coding structure needs `union`... it's just a simple binary tree.